# a question about directional derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

$$B_+ = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid  y>x^2 \}. $$
$$C_+ =\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0<y \leq x^2 \}.$$
$$B_- = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y<- x^2 \}.$$
$$ C_-=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0> y \geq - x^2 \}.$$ 
$$ L=\{(s,0) \mid s \in \mathbb{R} \}.$$

Consider $$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ defined by $$f(\vec{x})=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $\vec{x} \in B_+ \cup B_-$} \\
1 & \text{if $\vec{x} \in C_+ \cup C_-$} \\
s & \text{if $\vec{x} \in L$}
\end{cases} $$

(1) prove that the directional derivative of f at $\vec{0}$ exists for every direction $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

(2) does the directional derivative have the property that $$(\partial_{\vec{v} +\vec{w}} f) (\vec{0})=(\partial_{\vec{v}} f)(\vec{0})+(\partial_{\vec{w}} f)(\vec{0}) \ \forall \vec{v},\vec{w} \in \mathbb{R}^2$$

In question (1), $\text{if $h\vec{v} \in C_+ \cup C_-$}$, then $$\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h\vec{v})-f(\vec{0})}{h}=\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}=\infty$$. so i dont think the directional derivative exists for all directions. am i doing wrong here? And i dont know how to approach question (2), it seems like there are too many possibilities.

Comment: For any in $\mathbf v =(x_v,y_v)\in C_+\cup C_- $ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $h\mathbf v\in B_+\cup B_-$ when $|h|<\delta.$  That is, when $h$ is small enough $(hx_v)^2< |hy_v|$